# Export from MS Access to Excel when Access has an "Nz" expression using python

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I have an Access Table that I am trying to export to excel, but the access table (and some of the tables it calls on) use "Nz" expressions. I have tried replacing Nz with IIf(IsNull( and even coalesce, but I can't seem to get anything to work. I know the pyodbc access driver doesn't support he Nz expression so I am trying to figure out a work around. Also, I do not have permission to make any changes to the Access db (that would likely be the easiest solution.

The other issue is some of the columns in the join also have NZ expressions. Maybe something that would give a blanket value of 0 for any Nz expression the script comes across? I don't work with sql much so that may be easy, but I have not been able to figure out how.

I have run the code on tables that do not have a Nz expression and it works so I know the driver/cnxn is correct.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

ly_rep_temp_path = r"C:\examplePath\msAccessFile.accdb"
temp_path = r"C:\example\temoraryStorage"


driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'


cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver=driver, DBQ=ly_rep_temp_path)


sql = """
SELECT rep.old, rep.new, Left(Nz([oldI].[mName],""),10) AS oldM, Left(Nz([newI].[mName],""),10) AS newM, oldI.primary AS oldS, newI.primary AS newS, oldI.primaryMR AS oldR, newI.primaryM AS newR,
FROM export_byI INNER JOIN ((rep INNER JOIN availableI AS oldI ON rep.olIs = oldI.isI) INNER JOIN availableI AS newI ON rep.nIsI = newI.isI) ON export_byI.IstI = rep.nwIsI
ORDER BY rep.nwIsI;
"""

crsr = cnxn.execute(sql)
for row in crsr.fetchall():
    lpd_df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
    print(lpd_df.columns)
    lpd_df.to_excel(temp_path + '/zFinal.xlsx')
    full_export_path = (temp_path + '/zFinal.xlsx')
    # return full_export_path
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

I get the following error when I run the code:
"pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'Nz' in expression. (-3102) (SQLExecDirectW)")"

Comment: As a replacement for `Nz(thing, "")` did you try `IIf(IsNull(thing), '', thing)` ? I just tried it and it seems to work for me…. (Note the single quotes in the replacement.)

Comment: I did try that and it does work for exporting the visible Nz expressions in the sql. I should have clarified, the main issue is the Nz expressions in some of the tables called in the join tables that are not visible in the sql to replace with 'code' IIf(IsNull(thing), '', thing) 'code'. I think I need something that would work on a basic sql like 'SELECT * FROM tableWithMultNZExpressions'.

Comment: I did try that and it does work for exporting the visible Nz expressions in the sql. I should have clarified, the main issue is the Nz expressions in some of the tables called in the join tables that are not visible in the sql to replace with `IIf(IsNull(thing), '', thing)`. I think I need something that would work on a basic sql like `SELECT * FROM tableWithMultNZExpressions`code`. -edited to make markdown code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we have a table named [Donor]

```
DonorID  DonorName  Comments     
-------  ---------  -------------
      1  Gord       cheapskate   
      2  Bill                    
      3  Marsha     Jan's nemesis
```

and a saved query named [query1] that uses `Nz()`

```
SELECT Donor.DonorID, Donor.DonorName, Nz([Comments],"(no comment)") AS txt
FROM Donor;
```

which yields the following in the Microsoft Access application itself

```
DonorID  DonorName  txt          
-------  ---------  -------------
      1  Gord       cheapskate   
      2  Bill       (no comment) 
      3  Marsha     Jan's nemesis
```

if we try to do `crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM query1")` in pyodbc we get

> "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'Nz' in expression. (-3102)

because `Nz()` is not a built-in function of the Access Database Engine (ACE); it is part of the VBA Expression Engine. Therefore, in order to execute that query from Python we need to use [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) and COM automation to run an instance of MSACCESS.EXE and execute the query that way:

```py
"""
requires: pip install pywin32
"""
import win32com.client

# ACE.DAO constants
dbOpenDynaset = 2

msa = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
msa.OpenCurrentDatabase(r"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb")
db = msa.CurrentDb()
rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM query1", dbOpenDynaset)
while not rst.EOF:
    print(rst.Fields("txt").Value)
    rst.MoveNext()
"""console output:
cheapskate
(no comment)
Jan's nemesis
"""
msa.Quit()
```

Edit: If you want to export the query to Excel you can do that directly from the `Access.Application` instance:

```py
acExport = 1
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml = 10
msa.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(
    acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "query1", r"C:\__tmp\test.xlsx"
)
msa.Quit()
```

Comment: This works for letting me view the data with the print command, but I am stuck on getting it to export to excel. Going through pywin32 docs now trying to figure it out.

Comment: Full code that worked to export Access Tables with an `Nz` expression(s) to `.csv`. 
`"""
requires: pip install pywin32
"""
import win32com.client

# ACE.DAO constants
dbOpenDynaset = 2

msa = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
msa.OpenCurrentDatabase(r"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb")
db = msa.CurrentDb()
# Line below is probably superfluous
rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tableNamet", dbOpenDynaset)
acExportDelim = 2
msa.DoCmd.TransferText(acExportDelim, None, "tableName", "export_path.csv"), True`

Comment: Note: Exporting to excel is probably possible with modifying solution... otherwise pandas could be used to convert `.csv` to `.xlsx`.